# Chart.js 4 x-axis scroll with live updating graph

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js to create a graph that automatically update every 500ms checking if new new data from the backend exist. If there's a new data, it adds it to the graph

```
setInterval(function(){
    let num = pick_numb()

    num.then(function(result) {
        addData(myLiveChart, label_index++, result)
        // Update one of the points in the second dataset
        myLiveChart.update();
        })
}, 500);

function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
}

async function pick_numb() {
    let random_number_generated = await eel.pick_number(0)();
    return random_number_generated;
}
```

Now, because I can receive tons of data; I have my graph filling very fast and I can no more read it (see screenshot)

[image: graph]

I've tried to create a double div with an x-scroll as

```
 <style>
            .chartWrapper {
               position: relative;
            }
            .chartWrapper > canvas {
               position: absolute;
               left: 0;
               top: 0;
               pointer-events:none;
            }
            .chartAreaWrapper {
               width: 600px;
               overflow-x: scroll;
            }
        </style>

    <div class="chartWrapper">
             <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
                 <canvas id="updating-chart" width="1200" height="500"></canvas>
             </div>
          </div>
```

But it doesn't work.

I'm using Boostrap to format my page so, that's maybe the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use [Streaming Plugin](https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-streaming/latest/) and [Zoom Plugin](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-zoom/latest/)

```
var myLiveChart = new Chart(ctx,{
  type: 'line',
  data: startingData,
  options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'realtime',   // x axis will auto-scroll from right to left
                realtime: {         // per-axis options
                  duration: 10000,  // data in the past 20000 ms will be displayed
                  refresh: 500,    // onRefresh callback will be called every 1000 ms
                  delay: 10,      // delay of 1000 ms, so upcoming values are known before plotting a line
                  pause: false,     // chart is not paused
                  ttl: 60000,   // data will be automatically deleted as it disappears off the chart
                  frameRate: 30,    // data points are drawn 30 times every second

                  // a callback to update datasets
                  onRefresh: chart => {

                        let m1 = pick_counter_m1()

                        m1.then(function(result) {
                                 // query your data source and get the array of {x: timestamp, y: value} objects

                                chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(
                                {
                                x: Date.now(),
                                y: result
                              });

                        })

                        
                  }
              }
            },
            y: {
                type: 'linear',
                min: 0,
                max: 2100
            }
        },
        plugins: {
          zoom: {
            // Assume x axis has the realtime scale
            zoom: {
              pinch: {
                enabled: true       // Enable pinch zooming
              },
              wheel: {
                enabled: true       // Enable wheel zooming
              },
              mode: 'x'             // Allow zooming in the x direction
            }
          }
        }
    }
});
```